# pandas multilinear regression from series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I am doing a multilinear regression where y, x1, x2 are all from different dataframes. I have searched on the website for a while, but couldn't find an answer. All questions seem to assume x1 and x2 belong to the same dataframe, i.e. df[['x1', 'x2']]. I have three dataframes, df_A, df_B and df_C:

```
df_A:
               a    b    c    d    e    f
2011-01-01    0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
2011-02-01    0.2  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2
2011-03-01    0.2  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2

df_B:
               a    b    c    d    e    f
2011-01-01    0.5  0.5  0.4  0.5  0.1  0.5
2011-02-01    0.2  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2
2011-03-01    0.2  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2

df_C:
               a    b    c    d    e    f
2011-01-01    0.5  0.5  0.4  0.5  0.1  0.5
2011-02-01    0.2  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2
2011-03-01    0.2  0.5  0.3  0.3  0.1  0.4
```

Basically they are all in the same format. What I want to do is to loop over each index (the last two lines is incorrect, but it's what I want to achieve):

```
df_D = df_A (dataframe to record regression residuals)

for i in range(len(df_A)):
    y = df_A.iloc[i, :]
    x1 = df_B.iloc[i, :]
    x2 = df_C.iloc[i, :]
    RollOLS=sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant([x1, x2])).fit()
    df_D.iloc[i,:] = RollOLS.resid
```

I tried to create a data frame but received an error message:

```
pd.Dataframe[x1, x2]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscribable
```

Any tips (from how to create the correct data frame to change the entire set up to numpy array) would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I changed the regression line to:

```
RollOLS=sm.OLS(y,pd.DataFrame([x1, x2])).fit()
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,1) (2,1)
```

Update2: I added a .transpose() after the dataframe, and it seems to be working now.

Comment: That specific error message comes from the subscript brackets `[]` after the `DataFrame` constructor. `pd.DataFrame()` always takes `()`, never `[]`. But you will have to concatenate `x1` and `x2` and pass the result to `DataFrame`. Try something like `pd.DataFrame([x1, x2])`.

Comment: thanks! i used your advice and added a transpose. it seems to be working now

Comment: great to hear and happy coding